# How do we take this expectation?

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, multivariable-calculus, expectation

Suppose $X \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu, \Sigma\right)$ and $A$ is a symmetric matrix. How do I evaluate the following expectation:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{X'A'X}\right] $$?

Comment: **Hint:** There exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that $A' = S'DS$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose (diagonal) entries are $1,-1,$ and $0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That means matrices $A,D$ are similar with same eigenvalues. I'm afraid I haven't heard of any theorem that states any symmetric matrix has eigenvalues consisting only of $1,-1$ and $0$... Is there?

Comment: That's $S'$, not $S^{-1}$! The theorem is "Sylvester's law of inertia".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom ohhhhhhhh!!! Then it transforms into a form of mgf of chi-square distribution! Thanks!!

Comment: For nonsingular $\Sigma$, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/453178/119261.